# BATCH SCRIPT: Checking if file exist in folder using forloops

Tags: batch-file, pdf

I am trying to figure it out if file in the same folder as the batch file exist.

The files in the folder will be like

123.pdf
124.pdf
125.pdf
126.pdf

The files to check are listed in a nr.txt file like
124.pdf
126.pdf

If file exist, the file should be copied in another folder called nr, located in the same folder as the batch like %~dp0\nr\

here is what I got so far

```
@echo off
SET m=0
for /f %%G in ('dir *.pdf /b') do (for /f %%i in (nr.txt) do (
if %%i==%%G (
echo %%i found
::copy %%i %~dp0\nr\
) else (
SET m=1
echo %m%
)
)
if %m%==1 (
echo %%i not found
SET m=0
)
)
pause
```

My Problem is, SET m=1 doesn't set the variable.

Thank you in advance for your help

EDIT:

Thank you, I am getting closer.

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
SET m=0
for /f %%i in (nr.txt) do (for /f %%G in ('dir *.pdf /b') do (
if /I %%i==%%G (
echo %%i found
) else (
SET m=1
)
)
if !m!==1 (
echo %%i not found
SET m=0
)
)
pause

H:\Neuer Ordner (2)>check.bat
123.pdf found
123.pdf not found
126.pdf found
126.pdf not found
128.pdf not found
```

Problem is, it still tell me that it doesn't find 123.pdf but it is there. It found it once.

I tried to swithc the for loops but same issue.

Problem is, it will go through all files in Dir and match. It will match but always dismatch. Any idea how i can just display find message if the file is there ?

Thank you very much

Comment: 1. you need [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) as you write *and* read variable `m` in the same block of code; this can be avoid though when using `set "m=something"` for `set m=1` and `set "m="` for `set m=0` and use `if defined m` instead of `if %m%==1`; for echoing `m` you sould still need delayed expansion though; 2. consider to add `"delims="` to the `for /F` loops; 3. `if %%i==%%G` should be changed to `if /I "%%i"=="%%G"`; 4. avoid `::` comments in loops/blocks;

Comment: Instead of looping through your inputfile and check if the entry matches an existing file, why don't you loop through your files (using `forfiles`) and check with `findstr` if its filename is present or not in your inputfile?

Comment: Not sure how forfile works with findstr. I looked it up but I have no clue how to connect these both functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could probably do from a batch file like this:

```bat
@For /F Delims^=^ EOL^= %%A In ('Type "nr.txt"') Do @XCopy "%%~A" "nr\" /Y >Nul 2>&1
```

If you want the unnecessary `Echo`es:

```bat
@Echo Off
For /F Delims^=^ EOL^= %%A In ('Type "nr.txt"') Do If Exist "%%~A" (
    Echo %%A Found
    XCopy "%%~A" "nr\" /Y >Nul 2>&1) Else Echo %%A Not Found
Pause
```

Comment: @SimKa, if the solution works for you, please consider marking it as accepted, _by clicking on the large check mark to the left of the answer_.